# Apache HttpClient 4.5 cross host redirect

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, http-redirect

Here is my scenario

I am calling a url from HOSTA
http://www.hosta.com/something

This is redirecting me to the HOSTB url
http://www.hostb.com/something

This is response code which I gets from url a

**http-outgoing-5 << HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily**

**http-outgoing-5 << Location: www.hostb.com/something**

**Redirecting to www.hostb.com/something**

**http-outgoing-10 >>  Host: hosta.com**

In the last line I see the host header is set to HOSTA which is wrong.

Here is the code I am using

This is how connection is created

```
private PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
HttpClientBuilder builder= HttpClients.custom();

builder.setMaxConnPerRoute(50)
    .setConnectionManager(cm)
    .setConnectionTimeToLive(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
    .setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy())
    .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
    .setServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(retryStrategy)
    .setKeepAliveStrategy(keepAliveStrategy)
    .setRetryHandler(myRetryHandler);
```

Method to call the request

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
post.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
post.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
post.setHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
post.setConfig(requestConfig);
if (origin != null) {
    post.setHeader("Origin", origin);
}
if (host != null) {
    post.setHeader("Host", host);
}
if (referer != null) {
    post.setHeader("Referer", referer);
}
//some more code
```

I am using the automatic redirection (using  LaxDirectStrategy) which are working fine. But in this particular case I am getting issue.

is there any way to update the HOST header in case of cross host redirect  or automatic redirection can be stopped for one particular request?

Comment: Any success here? Even I am facing the same with macy URL

Comment: @SandeepDas Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64557806/363573

Answer (score 0):

I used the RequestConfig to disable/enable the redirection for particular request.

By Default I have redirection enabled.Whenever I wanted it to disable I used

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setRedirectsEnabled(false).build();//disable redirect
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

post.setConfig(requestConfig);//poass the request config to request
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with HttpClient 4.5.9 (and 4.5.13 too). It turned out that I was inadvertently writing the `Host` header.

HttpClient keeps the `Host` header if it is already defined in a request.

From [Oleg Kalnichevski](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=olegk) :

> *One ought not mess with HTTP transport headers such as 'Host' (...) and let HttpClient generate the appropriate header values instead.(...) As far as the 'Host' header is concerned HttpClient simply **does not overwrite the existing value** assuming that the user knows better.*
>
> Oleg

Reference: [in case of a redirect a wrong host param is set to http header](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1452?focusedCommentId=13882744&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13882744)